Relation between the power radiated by a point source in an homogenous lossless media with the distance
In a question I have come across regarding the power of a point source, it claimed that the relation between power radiated by a point source in a lossless homogenous medium  i.e.,
$$\Large\unicode{x222f}\normalsize_s \ \vec{P}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \hat{n}~ds$$
falls off with the distance from the source, following the inverse square law.
My thinking is that while the power density (which is given by the poynting vector $\vec{P}$ in the integral) falls off with the inverse square law, the total power itself (the integral as a whole) remains constant.
That is the decrease in $|{\vec{P}}|=\frac{P}{4\pi r^2}$  with $r^2$ is compensated with the surface area of a sphere $s=4\pi r^2$ which increases with $r^2$.
I would appreciate a through explanation on this please.
The exact question is
"Consider the following statements regarding the complex Poynting vector $\vec{P}$  for the power radiated by a point source in an infinite homogeneous and lossless medium. $Re(\vec{P})$ denotes the real part of $\vec{P}$, S denotes a spherical surface whose centre is at the point source, and $\hat{n}$denotes the unit surface normal on S. Which of the following statements is TRUE?
a)$Re(\vec{P})$ remains constant at any radial distance from the source
b)$Re(\vec{P})$ increases with increasing radial distance from the source
c)  $\Large\unicode{x222f}\normalsize_s Re(\vec{P})\cdot\hat{n}~dS$ remains constant at any radial distance from the source
d)$\Large\unicode{x222f}\normalsize_s Re(\vec{P})\cdot\hat{n}~dS$  decreases with increasing radial distance from the source"

Let's see the question as the wording is obviously important.

@Farcher  I have added the question

The rate of energy travelled through per unit area i.e. the amount of energy flowing through per unit area in the perpendicular direction to the incident energy per unit time is called Poynting vector.
Poynting theorem  states that the net power flowing out of a given volume is equal to the time rate of decrease in the energy stored within the volume minus the conduction losses.
It only carries physical significance when it is integrated over a closed volume with a negative sign:
where s is the surface which encloses the volume. The integration represents a total rate of loss (negative sign) of electromagnetic energy from a volume where ( where charge particles and currents interact with electromagnetic field) electromagnetic energy flows in. Hence it is playing essential part in electromagnetic energy conservation.
The power per unit area falls off with the square
of the distance from the source. This is expected, from conservation of energy.
The energy in any part of the electromagnetic wave is the sum of the energies of the electric and magnetic fields. This energy per unit volume, or energy density u, is the sum of the energy density from the electric field and the energy density from the magnetic field.
The energy passing through area  $A$ in time  $\Delta t$ is
$$ u\times \text{volume}=uAc\Delta t.$$
The energy per unit area per unit time passing through a plane perpendicular to the wave, called the energy flux and denoted by  $P$ , can be calculated by dividing the energy by the area  $A$ and the time interval  $\Delta t$
$$P=\frac{\text{Energy passing area A in time } \Delta t}{ A\Delta t}=Uc;$$ As you see area terms vanishes.
You will better understand think of a light bulb , how light intensity will change with distance, visible light is also electromagnetic radiation.

Welcome Barış Gürbüz - you may want to take a look at this MathJax guide, it can help you type mathematical expressions so they are more readable and clear.

@Barış Gürbüz so do you think my is argument correct?
